Type safety in Navigation Compose gives Serializer for class 'Companion' is not found error
I have to use built-in type safe APIs to provide compile-time type safety for navigation graph, as said here

You can use built-in type safe APIs to provide compile-time type safety for your navigation graph. These APIs are available when your app uses the Navigation Compose or Navigation Kotlin DSL. They are available as of Navigation 2.8.0.

I have:
libs.versions.toml
[versions]
.
.
.
composeNavigation = "2.8.0-beta02"
serialization = "1.6.3"
org-jetbrains-kotlin-jvm = "2.0.0"


[libraries]
.
.
.
navigation-compose = { module = "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose", version.ref = "composeNavigation" }
kotlinx-serialization-json = { module = "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json", version.ref = "serialization"}


[plugins]
.
.
.
kotlin-serialization = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization", version.ref = "kotlin" }
org-jetbrains-kotlin-jvm = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm", version.ref = "org-jetbrains-kotlin-jvm" }

App Top-level build.gradle.kts
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
@Suppress("DSL_SCOPE_VIOLATION") // TODO: Remove once KTIJ-19369 is fixed
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.compose.compiler) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.com.google.dagger.hilt.android) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.com.google.devtools.ksp) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.androidx.room) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm) apply false
}

and Module-level build.gradle.kts
@Suppress("DSL_SCOPE_VIOLATION") // TODO: Remove once KTIJ-19369 is fixed
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
    alias(libs.plugins.com.google.devtools.ksp)
    alias(libs.plugins.com.google.dagger.hilt.android)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.serialization)
    // Existing plugins
    alias(libs.plugins.compose.compiler)
    alias(libs.plugins.androidx.room)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.being.coder.app.newtodo"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.being.coder.app.newtodo"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_17.toString()
    }

    kotlin {
        sourceSets.all {
            languageSettings.enableLanguageFeature("ExplicitBackingFields")
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }

    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }

    room {
        schemaDirectory("$projectDir/schemas")
    }

}

dependencies {

    // Other dependencies
    implementation(libs.navigation.compose)
    implementation(libs.kotlinx.serialization.json)

}

Setting up Navigation as:
@Composable
fun SetupNavigation(
    navController: NavHostController
) {
    val screens = remember(navController) {
        Screens(navController = navController)
    }

    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = Home
    ) {
        addHomeScreen(
            navigateToTaskScreen = screens.detail
        )    
    }
}

@Serializable
data class Home(
    val action: String
)

@Serializable
data class Details(
    val id: Int
)

fun NavGraphBuilder.addHomeScreen(
    navigateToTaskScreen: (Int) -> Unit
){
    composable<Home>{
        HomeScreen(navigateToTaskScreen = navigateToTaskScreen)
    }

}

class Screens(
    navController: NavHostController
) {
    val home: (Action) -> Unit = {
        navController.navigate(Home(it.name)) {
            popUpTo(Home) { inclusive = true }
        }
    }

    val detail: (Int) -> Unit = {
        navController.navigate(Details(it))
    }
}

Finally in MainActivity
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private lateinit var navController: NavHostController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            NewTodoTheme {
                navController = rememberNavController()
                SetupNavigation(
                    navController = navController
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

with all this when I run the App I get:
2024-06-02 23:00:10.811 25777-25777 AndroidRuntime          com.being.coder.app.newtodo          E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main (Ask Gemini)
                                                                                                    Process: com.being.coder.app.newtodo, PID: 25777
                                                                                                    kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Serializer for class 'Companion' is not found.
                                                                                                    Please ensure that class is marked as '@Serializable' and that the serialization compiler plugin is applied.
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.serialization.internal.Platform_commonKt.serializerNotRegistered(Platform.common.kt:90)
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.serialization.SerializersKt__SerializersKt.serializer(Serializers.kt:299)
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.serialization.SerializersKt.serializer(Unknown Source:1)
                                                                                                        at androidx.navigation.NavGraph.setStartDestination(NavGraph.kt:403)
                                                                                                        at androidx.navigation.NavGraphBuilder.build(NavGraphBuilder.kt:321)
                                                                                                        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt.NavHost(NavHost.kt:716)
                                                                                                        at com.being.coder.app.newtodo.nav.SetupNavigationKt.SetupNavigation(SetupNavigation.kt:19)
                                                                                                        at com.being.coder.app.newtodo.MainActivity$onCreate$1$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:24)
                                                                                                        at com.being.coder.app.newtodo.MainActivity$onCreate$1$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:22)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:401)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.material3.TextKt.ProvideTextStyle(Text.kt:352)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.material3.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:72)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.material3.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:71)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:380)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.material3.MaterialThemeKt.MaterialTheme(MaterialTheme.kt:64)
                                                                                                        at com.being.coder.app.newtodo.ui.theme.ThemeKt.NewTodoTheme(Theme.kt:53)
                                                                                                        at com.being.coder.app.newtodo.MainActivity$onCreate$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:22)
                                                                                                        at com.being.coder.app.newtodo.MainActivity$onCreate$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:21)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView.Content(ComposeView.android.kt:441)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:259)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:258)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:380)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.CompositionLocalsKt.ProvideCommonCompositionLocals(CompositionLocals.kt:216)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:132)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:131)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:380)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt.ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:121)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:155)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:154)
2024-06-02 23:00:10.815 25777-25777 AndroidRuntime          com.being.coder.app.newtodo          E      at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109) (Ask Gemini)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:401)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:154)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:133)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.ActualJvm_jvmKt.invokeComposable(ActualJvm.jvm.kt:97)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:3593)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.composeContent$runtime_release(Composer.kt:3520)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeContent(Composition.kt:743)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_release(Recomposer.kt:1114)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeInitial(Composition.kt:649)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:635)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:133)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:124)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.setOnViewTreeOwnersAvailable(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1597)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.setContent(Wrapper.android.kt:124)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.onStateChanged(Wrapper.android.kt:180)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.jvm.kt:320)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.jvm.kt:198)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:131)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:124)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onAttachedToWindow(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1678)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:20820)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3550)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3557)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3557)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3557)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3557)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2730)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2234)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:9027)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1105)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:896)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:815)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1090)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7886)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:568)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1045)

Any solution to this please.

The line that is failing is startDestination = Home - you're using the Companion object of Home as the start destination, which doesn't make any sense. If Home is a data class, you need to pass an instance of that class, but using a data class for the fixed start destination of your app doesn't make any sense, since there should only be one instance of your home screen. Why is your Home a data class at all rather than an object?

Q: Why is your Home a data class at all rather than an object?
Ans: because I have to Pass Action, as argument/parameter

So what is the default action - the one your app starts on (e.g., Home("default")? Why isn't that your start destination?

Had the same problem.  @ianhanniballake commentary solved it.

@ianhanniballake I'm with the same exception, but using popUpTo(MyClassWithSerializableAnnotation), do you know what is wrong?

In my case I was trying to navigate while popping some screens off the Backstack. So the error originated from popUpTo(CustomClass). either remove this line or pass some default values.

@JohnSmith Yep! passing some default values, worked like a charm.

Like stated in the commentary either the route Home needs to be an object or you need to instantiate the Home class like Home("this is the action") in the startDestination, like this
@Composable
fun SetupNavigation(
    navController: NavHostController
) {
val screens = remember(navController) {
    Screens(navController = navController)
}

NavHost(
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = Home("action to perform")
) {
    addHomeScreen(
        navigateToTaskScreen = screens.detail
    )    
}

}

in my case i get the class instance
@Serializable
data class OrderParentScreenRoute(val data: String)

navigation<OrderGraph>(startDestination = OrderParentScreenRoute::class) {
                    composable<OrderParentScreenRoute> { backStackEntry ->
                        val data = backStackEntry
                            .toRoute<OrderParentScreenRoute>().data
                            .fromJsonString<OrderServiceDetailResponse>()
                        OrderParentScreen(
                            data = data,
                            onBack = {
                                navController.popBackStack()
                            },
                            onUnauthorized = {
                                navController.navigateAndClean(Login)
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }

